# Zoyto API Call using PHP soap

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am integrating Zoyto API https://test.zoyto.com/zfulfillment/api/ in one of my website. I have tested API calling its function **getOrderStatus** and it works fine. But when I try calling function **newOrders** I am getting response.

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["newOrdersResult"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (4) { ["timestamp"]=> string(20) "2015-09-15T03:45:26Z" ["result_code"]=> string(3) "200" ["error_message"]=> string(48) "The request was valid and is processed by Zoyto." ["order_statuses"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (1) { ["Order_Status"]=> object(stdClass)#5 (5) { ["client_order_id"]=> string(8) "TESTPN01" ["zoyto_order_id"]=> int(0) ["order_status_code"]=> string(8) "REJECTED" ["order_type"]=> string(14) "CUSTOMER_ORDER" ["error_message"]=> string(24) "411:The city is invalid." } } } }
```

Below is my code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); 
function createSignature($api_secret, $method, $timestamp, $service_name) {
    $toSign = strtolower($service_name) . strtolower($method) . strtolower($timestamp);
    $sig = hash_hmac('sha1', $toSign, $api_secret, true);
    return base64_encode($sig);
}
/********Test API*******/
$api_key = '3D84D210-AA9B-4968-B6A1-25FB6A8D556D';
$url = "https://test.zoyto.com/zfulfillment/api/?WSDL";
$api_secret = 'EEF53F44E6914C2799F2A19AAF28F27B';

//$method = 'getOrderStatus';
$method = 'newOrders';

$timestamp  = date('Y-m-d').'T'.date("h:i:s").'Z'; 
$service_name    = 'Zoyto Fulfillment Service';

$sig = createSignature($api_secret, $method, $timestamp, $service_name);

//echo $timestamp;

$client = new SoapClient($url);
/* Set your parameters for the request */
$orderStatus = array(
  "api_key" => $api_key,
  "timestamp" => $timestamp,
  "signature" => $sig,
  "version" => "2.0",
  "order_ids" => array("RTSC100052438")
);
$shipping = array(
    "first_name" => "Calvin",
    "last_name" => "Hart",
    "address_1" => "Apt 1",
    "address_2" => "5143 West Bellfort Ave",
    "zip_code" => "77035",
    "state" => "CA",
    "country" => "USA",
    "country_code" => "US",
    "phone_number" => "0401234567",
    "city" => "Riva",
    "email" => "myemail@gmail.com"
);
$billing = $shipping;
$line_item = array(
    "client_line_item_id" => "1",
    "quantity" => "1",
    "ship_method_code" => "PRIT",
    "client_part_number" => "SAFARI-XXL",
    "description" => "Description",
    "parent_line_item_id" => 0,
    "line_item_amount" => 1.00
);

$newOrder = array(
  "api_key" => $api_key,
  "timestamp" => $timestamp,
  "signature" => $sig,
  "version" => "2.0",
  "orders" => array(array(  "shipping_address" => $shipping,
                            "billing_address" => $billing,
                            "client_order_id" => "TESTPN01",
                            "order_type" => "CUSTOMER_ORDER",
                            "line_items" => array($line_item),
                            "created_at" => $timestamp,
                            "total_product_amount" => 1.00,
                            "total_discount_amount" => 0.00,
                            "total_tax_amount" => 0.00,
                            "total_shipping_amount" => 0.00,
                            "total_handling_amount" => 0.00,
                            "total_order_amount" => 1.00,
                            "group_shipment_number" => 0
                        )
              )
);
//$params = $orderStatus;
$params = $newOrder;
/* Invoke webservice method with your parameters, in this case: Function1 */
$response = $client->__soapCall($method, array($params));

/* Print webservice response */
var_dump($response);

//var_dump($client->__getFunctions()); 
//var_dump($client->__getTypes());
```

It looks there is some error in preparing shipping address. Is there anybody who can help please. I am search from last two days but no success.

Thanks in advance for all readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the WSDL from https://test.zoyto.com/zfulfillment/api/Service.asmx?WSDL, you could generate the corresponding package from [wsdltophp.com](https://www.wsdltopph.com) in order to be sure on how to structure your request in PHP as every element will be a PHP object with setters/getters.
Let me know if you need any additional help,

Comment: Thanks Mikaël. We fixed the bug after assigning new array of address to billing_address instead of assigning it shipping_address. Your provided tool looks amazing. I will try in future.